Simplifying Minimization on $(x-y)^2-z^2=1$ : Possible?
Let $A=\left\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid(x-y)^2-z^2=1\right\}$, and I want to find all points in $A$ that are nearest to $(0,0,0)$. I tried to use Lagrange's method:
\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{L}(x,y,z) = \sqrt{x^2 +y^2+z^2} - \lambda ((x-y)^2-z^2-1)
\end{equation}
But the calculations are too much, my question is can I write $(x-y)^2-1$ instead of $z^2$ and turn the problem into an unconstrained problem? Any help is appreciated in advance.

It is often simpler to minimize $r^2$ instead of $r$.

@HagenvonEitzen Can I just minimize $x^2+y^2+z^2$ using $(x-y)^2-z^2=1$?

@HagenvonEitzen I did what you did, and I found the following minimizers: $(0,0,1), (0,0,-1), (1/2, -1/2, 0), (-1/2, 1/2,0)$ but I am not sure about them.

There's another coordinate system $(s,t,z)$ with $s=(x-y)/\sqrt{2}$, $t=(x+y)/\sqrt{2}$, and the transition to that coordinate system preserves distances. In those coordinates, the equation is $2s^2-z^2=1$ and it's "clear" (relative to one's experience) that this is a hyperbolic cylinder with central axis along the $t$-axis, and its closest points to the origin are $(\pm1/\sqrt{2},0,0)$. Each with distance $1/\sqrt{2}$ from the origin.

I’m sorry but I don’t know the transition to another coordinate system @2'59'2

Or in spherical coordinates (more standard than my previous comment) the equation is $\rho^2\left(\sin^2\varphi\cdot(\cos\theta-\sin\theta)^2-\cos^2\varphi\right)=1$. You want to minimize $\rho$, so you want to maximize the two-variable expression $\sin^2\varphi\cdot(\cos\theta-\sin\theta)^2-\cos^2$ subject to no constraints. Maybe that would be helpful.

At this moment it does not seem so similar but I will work on it @2'59'2.

You want to minimize $\operatorname{dist}(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ subject to $z^2=(x-y)^2-1$. So yes, answering your question, you can minimize $$f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(x-y)^2-1}$$with no constraints on $x,y$. Except that really there are constraints, because we need $(x-y)^2-1\geq0$ for $z$ to be real.
Now you might as well minimize:
$$g(x,y)=f(x,y)^2=x^2+y^2+(x-y)^2-1$$

$g_x=4x-2y$
$g_y=4y-2x$

The solution to the system $\{g_z=0, g_y=0\}$ is $x=y=0$, which leaves $(x-y)^2-1\lt0$. So the minimization must actually happen somewhere along the boundary where $z=0$, that is: $(x-y)^2-1=0$. Now you are minimizing $x^2+y^2$ subject to the constraint $(x-y)^2-1=0$, which is equivalent to $x=y\pm1$.
So you are minimizing the (two versions of the) one-variable function $h(y)=(y\pm1)^2+y^2=2y^2\pm2y+1$. We have $h'(y)=4y\pm2=0\implies y=\mp\frac12$. And back track to find $(x,y,z)=\left(-\frac12,\frac12,0\right)$ or $(x,y,z)=\left(\frac12,-\frac12,0\right)$.

$\min \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ subject to $(x-y)^2-z^2=1$. it is equivalent to
$$
\min x^2+y^2+z^2 \quad \text { s. to }(x-y)^2-z^2=1 \text {. }
$$
So we con write Lagrangian as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x}=0 \Rightarrow 2 x-\lambda(2 x-2 y)=0 \ldots(1) \\
& \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y}=0 \Rightarrow 2 y-\lambda(-2 x+2 y)=0 \ldots(2) \\
& \begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial+}{\partial z}=0 \Rightarrow & 2 z^2-\lambda(-2 z)=0 \\
& \Rightarrow z(z-\lambda)=0 \\
& \Rightarrow z=0 \text { or } z=\lambda .
\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
$$
let us first consider $z=\lambda$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
& 2 x-z(2 x-2 y)=0 \Rightarrow 2 x=z(2 x-2 y) \ldots(3) \\
& 2 y-z(2 y-2 x)=0 \Rightarrow 2 y=-z(2 x-2 y) \ldots(4)
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
(3) \wedge(4) \Rightarrow x=-y \ldots . .(5)
$$
$$
\begin{aligned} (3)  \wedge(5) & \Rightarrow 2 x-z(4 x)=0 \\ & \Rightarrow 2 x(1-2 z)=0 \\ & \Rightarrow x=0 \text { or } z=1 / 2\end{aligned}
$$
$$
x=0 \Rightarrow y=0, z=\mp 1
$$
$z=1 / 2$ leads to a contradiction.
So the candidates ore $(0,0,1),(0,0,-1)$. Now let us assume $z=0$.
So the problem becomes
$$
\min x^2+y^2 s.to (x-y)^2=1
$$
equivalently,
$$
\min x^2+(x-1)^2 or \min x^2+(x+1)^2
$$
So let us delve into them:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \min 2 x^2-2 x+1 \\
\Rightarrow & 4 x-2=0 \\
\Rightarrow & x=1 / 2 \Rightarrow y=-1 / 2
\end{aligned}
$$
and for the other
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \min 2 x^2+2 x+1 \\
& \Rightarrow 4 x+2=0 \\
& \Rightarrow x=-1 / 2 \Rightarrow y=1 / 2
\end{aligned}
$$
So we have two new candidates $(1 / 2,-1 / 2,0),(-1 / 2,1 / 2,0$
$$
\begin{aligned}
& f(0,0,1)=1=f(0,0,-1) \\
& f(1 / 2,-1 / 2,0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=f(-1 / 2,1 / 2,0)
\end{aligned}
$$
so the minimizes are $(1 / 2,-1 / 2,0),(-1 / 2,1 / 2,0)$.

@underflow oh, you’re right, I couldn’t see it. Thank you so much.
